# The best way to import(merge)-export java db database

Tags: java, database, import, export

I have let's say two pc's.PC-a and PC-b which both have the same application installed with java db support.I want from time to time to copy the data from the database on PC-a to database to PC-b and vice-versa so the two PC's to have the same data all the time.
Is there an already implemented API in the database layer for this(i.e 1.export-backup database from PC-a 2.import-merge databases to PC-b) or i have to do this in the sql layer(manually)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short:  You can't do this without some work on your side.  SalesLogix fixed this problem by giving everything a site code, so here's how your table looked:

```
Customer: 
   SiteCode varchar,
   CustomerID varchar, 
   .... 
   primary key(siteCode, CustomerID)
```

So now you would take your databases, and match up each record by primary key.  Where there are conflicts you would have to provide a report to the end-user, on what data was different.

Say machine1:

```
   SiteCode|CustomerID|CustName     |phone         |email 
 1 XXX     |0001      |Customer1    |555.555.1212  |darth@example.com
```

and on machine2:

```
   SiteCode|CustomerID|CustName     |phone         |email 
 2 XXY     |0001      |customer2    |555.555.1213  |darth@nowhere.com 
 3 XXX     |0001      |customer1    |555.555.1212  |darth@nowhere.com
```

When performing a resolution:

- Record 1 and 3 are in conflict, because the PK matches, but the data doesnt (email is different).
- Record 2 is unique, and can freely exist in both databases.

There is *NO* way to do this automatically without error or data corruption or referential integrity issues.

Answer (score 2):

As you mention in the comments that you want to "merge" the databases, this sounds like you need to write custom code to do this, as presumably there could be conficts - the same key in both, but with different details against it, for example.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are using [Java DB (aka Derby)](http://developers.sun.com/javadb/) - in which case, assuming you just can't use a single instance, you can do a [backup/restore](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.3/adminguide/).

Comment: Thank you for your answer.Restoring results deletion of the default database.I want to merge the two dtatabases

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you have the database on one pc. and have all other pc's request data from the host pc

Comment: I work in a francise company which distributes the java program i develop in it's departments and i need to merge the databases from different locations.